# how to send an image from raspberry pi to web server?

Tags: networking, wifi

Looking for example codes on how to send images from Raspberry pi to a web server via wifi.
i am really new to raspberry pi and there's already a tomcat server.
I really need your help

Comment: Welcome. Uploading to a webserver takes place via HTTP, generally but not necessarily via an html interface.  Traditionally this is via a multipart upload form but there are other means as well. However, this is platform agnostic -- it doesn't matter whether the upload comes from a raspberry pi or your laptop, etc., it takes place exactly the same way (if you upload something via a web page, it does not matter what computer you are on, it is pretty much the same). You are better off pursuing web programming questions on our larger parent site, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: This is a networking related question

Answer (score 2):

I am sure that both hosts have SSH installed so another solution could be to use SCP/SFTP. If not, try to use a regular FTP client.

For example on your RaspberryPi:

```
scp /path/to/your/imag.jpg YourUser@Webserver:/path/to/destination/
```

Make sure that `YourUser` has permissions to write in your destination directory.
If you want to upload a directory don't forget to pass the `-r` option.

More information about using scp can be found here:

- [scp manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/scp.1.html)
- [How to Use SCP Command to Transfer Files/Folders in Linux](https://linux4one.com/how-to-use-scp-command-to-transfer-files-folders-in-linux/)

Answer (score 1):

That one is really easy.

You should read some tutorials about UNIX.

Use the **wget** command to upload or download stuff with web servers.

The basic syntax of this command is

```
wget http://website.com/files/file.zip
```

This would download the file into your working directory (meaning you'd have to do this from webserver to raspberry)

Here is a basic tutorial for wget:

[Using WGET](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/wget.htm)

Another strong program is **curl**

It would look like

```
curl -O -C - file:///path/to/some/file
```

[curl man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/curl.1.html)

This is really a trivial feature of every linux system nowadays, and I guess with the 2 links I posted you should be able to fiddle something together. (If not try watching a youtube video to these programs)

I hope you can manage it

saraba

Comment: aren't these solutions to DOWNload from a webserver instead of UPload?

Comment: @ON5MFJurgen I'm sure I used this for both ways already. Also, since a webserver normally is just another linux server, there should be no big deal on which device pulls from the other. (unless you have webhosting - where you only have a folder for you page) ; also I just wanted to provide OP with a basic idea on which programs there are, since he didn't show any efforts to code / learn something on his own

Comment: *"since a webserver normally is just another linux server"* -> That depends upon the context of use.  In this context, I would say it is most likely **a piece of software** such apache or nginx.  But it is a very vague question.

Comment: @clockw0rk, "wget" is not easy for newbies.  I remember a couple of years ago, the first time I learned to use "wget", it took me 3 hours to complete the job of wget, and untar something.  Of course I can now do it in minutes.  But at that time I was very discouraged and I did give up and stopped playing Rpi for one or two years, until Rpi2 came along, with GUI Desktop, though still slow. At that time I only Windows 7, and I knew how to google, but did not know how to search linux tools, and I did not know stack overflow or rpi stack exchange, ... :(

Comment: @tlfong01 Yes, I remember struggeling with it too, until the point I needed it at work and was forced to use it. Today I still would recommend everybody to go through the struggle and just try it until you get it, cause it is really mighty. "It seems difficult at first, but everything's difficult at first" [M. Miamoto, around 1600]